# Can I trigger a javascript function from a php function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am getting html data through js ajax function like this

```
function getData(dataSource,datasend)
{ 

var XMLHttpRequestObject = false; 

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
XMLHttpRequestObject = new 
ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", dataSource, true); 
XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
XMLHttpRequestObject.send('data='+escape(datasend));

XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() 
{ 
    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
        document.getElementById(datafin).innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
            //when the html has require data extecute this function
            if(html has needed data for the function){
                foo();
            }

    }
} 

function foo(){
     //stuff to do with the html when loaded
}
```

as far as i do it the html is generated by a php function. Now Is there way to trigger the `foo()` function in the html data generated or a way to send data that can trigger the function. Thanks

Comment: Either you can implement that function foo in Javascript or send the data to PHP function via another AJAX call

Comment: Sure you can but more surely you shouldn't

Comment: @A.Wolff the thing is when you send js in a ajax it get appended to the dom but how can you trigger or execute it after you append it

Comment: @SathyaRaj using any ajax callback or method relative to returned promise interface http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: @A.Wolff i looked at your q&a but it was about handling sync and async code i well aware of that and thats y i need something to send from php that could recognized in success function. so that i can call the foo() function . bcoz its an old code with html data is big i'd have to find without string manipulation ....

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this :

```
    <?php 

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> function foo()
{ alert('my home');} foo();</script>";echo "<script type='text/javascript'> foo()</scipt>";
    ?>
```

Comment: i have tried this but it didn't work but its got appended to the dom but no alert :|

Comment: i m pretty sure your code is not alert ... have you tried it. it only appends the function to dom ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use like,

in php file,

```
 echo '<script>foo();</script>';
```

javscript,

```
  function foo(){
     //stuff to do with the html when loaded
     alert('test');
  }
```

Comment: it didn't work either its same as mahmood's answer but still i want to execute foo() not getData() ....

Answer (score 0):

assuming that php,html,javascript is in the same file

```
<?php
$stuff_to_do = "anything";
$desicion_variable = ($access_db_or_anything)?"needed_foo":"dont_needed_foo";
.....
?>
<!-- html -->
<script>
function getData(dataSource,datasend)
{ 
......
    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
        document.getElementById(datafin).innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
            //when the html has require data extecute this function
            <?php 
            // condition_html_has_needed_data_for_the_function
            if ( $desicion_variable == "needed_foo" ){
                ?>
                foo();
                <?php
            }
            ?>
    }
}
function foo(){
     //stuff to do with the html when loaded
}
</script>
```

and if you have file js is separate of html and php: page_example.php events.js
page_example.php

```
<?php
$stuff_to_do = "anything";
$desicion_variable = ($access_db_or_anything)?"needed_foo":"dont_needed_foo";
.....
?>
<body data-optionFoo="<?php echo $desicion_variable ?>">
    <!-- html stuff -->
</body>
<script src="events.js"></script>
```

events.js

```
function getData(dataSource,datasend)
{ 
   .....
    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
        document.getElementById(datafin).innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
            //when the html has require data extecute this function
            var objDiv = document.getElementById("pnlOpcion");
            if ( objDiv.getAttribute('data-optionFoo') == "needed_foo" ){
                foo();
            }
    }
}
function foo(){
     //stuff to do with the html when loaded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to trigger the js function from php but in vein but i have achieve it by giving a dummy div in html data and checked it in success if present and triggered the function like this

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() 
{ 
    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
        document.getElementById(datafin).innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
            //when the html has require data extecute this function
            if($('#foo_div').length > 0){
                foo();
            }

    }
} 

function foo(){
     //stuff to do with the html when loaded
     //remove div after everything finished
     $('#foo_div').remove();
}
```

I still don't think that this is the properway to do it. Any Proper answer i'll greatly appreciate it.